# How can I use a slide switch to reverse polarity of this comparator circuit?

Tags: switches, comparator

This circuit is a simple photo-transistor switch with 2 independent threshold potentiometers. I've placed a switch to alter functionality of the comparator.

- Mode 1: Always ON. I simply connect the comparator positive input to VCC.
- Mode 2: Sensor dependent. The comparator input is connected to photo-transistor. When the light goes UP, the relay turns OFF.
- **Mode 3: [the question!]**. I want to reverse the mode 2 functionality - when the light goes UP, the relay turns ON. May be I should switch the location of photo-transistor and its 100k resistor, but I don't know how to do that with remaining pins of the switch.
- Mode 4: Always OFF. I simply connect the comparator positive input to GND.

Here's the schematic and a few notes:

[image: The schematic]

- The light sensor is a [photo-transistor](https://dammedia.osram.info/media/resource/hires/osram-dam-5452286/BPX%2081_EN.pdf), not a photodiode as in the schematic.
- The circuit works so the other "modes" described above seem to have no problem. They are tested.

The switch schematic:

[image: 2P4T switch]

Comment: What's the purpose of U2?

Comment: Show the correct circuit please.

Comment: @Ralph its the hysteresis. The relay turns on when the output of both comparators are high. and turns off when the output of both comparators are low.

Comment: @Andyaka It's all of it. it works with the exact same values. I just changed a few resistors to decrease power consumption.

Comment: I'll be happy if someone explains why the question got -1 so I can correct it

Comment: I downvoted it based on the fact that what you provided was not the correct schematic. Do you know how important it is the provide the exact schematic? The devil's in the detail and all we have here to go on is a circuit diagram that has a wrong component shown and incorrect values. It matters not one bit how representative of reality you think it is. What else might be wrong with it that you haven't mentioned?

Comment: @Andyaka The schematic is updated with exact same values used on the real board.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the circuit of U2 and reuse the comparator for the inverted operation. Hysteresis can be achieved by a simpler and more intuitive circuit, some options described here:
https://circuitcellar.com/resources/comparator-hysteresis-2/

Switch pins either row:

1: Comparator A

2: Comparator B (reversed opeartion to A)

3 and 4: Gate of transistor

5: Vcc

6: GND

Comment: The hysteresis used in the main schematic allows to change threshold levels independently. a simple hysteresis as the first schematic in the link, affects both thresholds with change in Rh. If I'm not wrong, we need 2 pots. one for offset and one for widening the thresholds.